# Running into 16MB BSON limit with Mongoose Populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am doing a really large Mongoose call with nested population, and then doing some processing on the data.

However, because of the nested populate call I am hitting the 16MB limit for a BSON document in Mongoose.

What's a solid way around this?

```
let allDocuments = await exampleModel.find({
    condition: true
  }).populate({path: 'tvShows', populate: {path: 'views'}});
```

[image]

Maybe I can break into into multiple calls? But I'm not sure a logical way to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own *paging* using `skip` and `limit` query parameters.

```
const query = yourModel.find({ /* your conditions here */ });
const batchSize = 100;

function mergeAllReducer( accumulator, currentValue ) {
  return accumulator.concat( currentValue );
}

query.count().then( total => {
  let skip = 0;
  const allQueries = [];
  while ( skip < total ) {
    allQueries.push( query.find()
      .skip( skip )
      .limit( batchSize )
      .populate({ path: 'tvShows', populate: { path: 'views' }})
    );
    skip += batchSize;
  }
  return Promise.all( allQueries );
})
.then( arrayOfArrays => arrayOfArrays.reduce( mergeAllReducer, [] ))
.then( result => {
  // do something with your populated result
});
```

Please note that you will still have to deal with all this memory being used and your javascript array size might still be larger than you VM can handle, so you could possibly try handling in batches as well, instead of working with the whole array.

Comment: Thanks, I've setup something similar, wish there was a way to raise the 16MB limit but whatever.

Comment: Usually it's not OK to load unlimited amount of data into memory; it is always a good practice to read data in chunks; even if you do need to process it all at once. It's very hard to think of a use case where batch reads cannot be used.